# How can I optionally include an HTML attribute with v-bind?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm creating a dynamic HTML input component. I want to **optionally** include `maxlength` i.e. if it's passed as a prop.

I have this in the template:

```
<input type="text" :id="id" :value="value" :maxlength="maxlength">
```

and the prop set like so:

```
props: {
    maxlength: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
    },
    [...]
 }
```

How can I handle the case where the maxlength should not be set. If I set it to `0` some browsers (at least) allow no entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved more or less by asking. :-)

The solution is to **set the value to `false`** not `0`.

I suppose I could change the default to `false` but I prefer to use a calculated value instead:

```
computed: {
    maxLenComputed: function () {
        return this.maxlength || false;
    },
    [...]
}
```